# Unhashable type: 'Series' in Pandas using DataFrame.query

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm trying to do a twitter sentiment analysis between Johnny Depp and Amber Heard. I've extracted the data during the period of 2021 and the Pandas DataFrame for both individuals are stored in `df_dict` dictionary described below. The error I am receiving is ***Unhashable type: 'Series'***.

As far as I've learnt is that this error happens when you have a dictionary that does not have a list or anything. I first tested it with a single key but I got the same error. I'm on a roadblock and don't know how to solve this issue.

**This is my preprocess method**

```
def preprocess(df_dict, remove_rows, keep_rows):
  for key, df in df_dict.items():
    print(key)
    initial_count = len(df_dict[key])
    df_dict[key] = (
      df
      # Make everything lower case
      .assign(Text=lambda x: x['Text'].str.lower())
      # Keep the rows that mention name 
      .query(f'Text.str.contains("{keep_rows[key]}")')
      # Remove the rows that mentioned the other three people.
      .query(f'~Text.str.contains("{remove_rows[key]}")')
      # Remove all the URLs
      .assign(Text=lambda x:x['Text'].apply(lambda s: re.sub(r'\w+:\/{2}[\d\w-]+(\.[\d\w-]+)*(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*', '', s)))
    )
    final_count = len(df_dict[key])
    print("%d tweets kept out of %d" % (final_count, initial_count))

  return df_dict
```

**This is the code I'm using to call preprocess method**

```
df_dict = {
    'johnny depp': johnny_data,
    "amber heard": amber_data
}

remove_rows = {
    'johnny depp': 'amber|heard|camila|vasquez|shannon|curry',
    "amber heard": 'johnny|depp|camila|vasquez|shannon|curry'
}

keep_rows = {
    'johnny depp': 'johnny|depp',
    "amber heard": 'amber|heard'
}

df_test_data = preprocess(df_dict, remove_rows, keep_rows)
```

I hope I've cleared up my issue on this forum and since this is my first post here, so I also hope I've followed all the regular protocols regarding posting.

I am attaching the the error message I received:
[Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNk1S.png)
[Error part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYo2i.jpg) [Error part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4U1d.png)

The link to the code is down below:
[Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Osnmn3xp7Hee-kz8ryg4kqfL6YM1Sg3V#scrollTo=09iJus1668XG)

Comment: show the full traceback, which line throws the error

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [**`DataFrame.query`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is really for simple logical operations, you cannot access Series methods of columns. As workaround, consider `assign` of flags to then `query` against. Consider also [**`Series.str.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for regex clean.

```py
df_dict[key] = (
    df
    # Make everything lower case
    .assign(
        Text = lambda x: x['Text'].str.lower(),
        keep_flag = lambda x: x['Text'].str.contains(keep_rows[key]),
        drop_flag = lambda x: x['Text'].str.contains(remove_rows[key])
    )
    # Keep the rows that mention name 
    .query("keep_flag == True")
    # Remove the rows that mentioned the other three people.
    .query("drop_flag == False")
    # Remove all the URLs
    .assign(
        Text = lambda x: x['Text'].str.replace(
            r'\w+:\/{2}[\d\w-]+(\.[\d\w-]+)*(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*', 
            '', 
            regex=True)
        )
    )
    .drop(["keep_flag", "drop_flag"], axis="columns")
)
```